# How can I change an object variable through a method called in another class?

Tags: java, oop

I'm having a little trouble with this problem. It's simple:

I want to use **defineBuyTax(6)/defineSellTax(5)** to change **txbuy/txsell**, so I can use **printTaxes** and see the values in terminal. But, I'am receiving the values 0 and 0, not 6 and 5 as expected. So, basically it is not changing the values in **Conversor()**;

I managed to fix it, creating a Conversor object to receive **defineBuyTax** and then manually prints it on the main function. Also, if I use **System.out.print(cm.txbuy)** inside the **defineBuyTax** method (as indicated in the code), it returns the right value.

So, **what I want to know** is: how can I change the variables in Conversor() so my **printTaxes** method do it's job correctly?

```
class Conversor {

    public double txbuy;
    public double txsell;

    public Conversor() {
        this.txbuy = 0;
        this.txsell = 0;
    }

    public Conversor defineBuyTax (double tax) {

        Conversor cm = new Conversor();
        cm.txbuy = tax;
        System.out.println(cm.txbuy);   
        return cm;
    }

    public Conversor defineSellTax (double tax) {

        Conversor cm = new Conversor();
        cm.txsell = tax;
        System.out.println(cm.txsell);  
        return cm;

    }

    void printTaxes() {
        System.out.println("Buy tax: "+txbuy);
        System.out.println("Sell tax : "+txsell);
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Conversor cm = new Conversor();

        cm.defineBuyTax(6.0);
        cm.defineSellTax(5.0);
        cm.printTaxes();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `this` instead of creating new instance of `Conversor` in each call of  `defineBuyTax` or `defineSellTax`:

```
class Conversor {

    public double txbuy;
    public double txsell;

    public Conversor() {
        this.txbuy = 0;
        this.txsell = 0;
    }

    public Conversor defineBuyTax (double tax) {
        this.txbuy = tax;
        System.out.println(this.txbuy);
        return this;
    }

    public Conversor defineSellTax (double tax) {
        this.txsell = tax;
        System.out.println(this.txsell);
        return this;
    }

    void printTaxes() {
        System.out.println("Buy tax: "+txbuy);
        System.out.println("Sell tax : "+txsell);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Conversor cm = new Conversor();
        cm.defineBuyTax(6.0);
        cm.defineSellTax(5.0);
        cm.printTaxes();
    }
}
```

The [`this`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_this.asp) keyword refers to the current object in a method or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `define...` methods return a new object you should chain your calls into one.

```
cm.defineBuyTax(6.0).defineSellTax(5.0).printTaxes();
```

If you on the other hand only want to work with a single instance, then the `define...` methods should update `this` and return `void`.

```
public void defineBuyTax(double tax) {
    this.txbuy = tax;
}

public void defineSellTax (double tax) {
    this.txsell = tax;
}
```

Note that the naming standard for setting a value for an instance variable is setX so if you want to use the second solution you should rename the methods to `setSellTax` and `setBuyTax`

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a Conversor object inside the define methods.
Even if you need to chain the calls it will not work that way.
The following code should work as you intend.

```
public class Conversor {

    public double txbuy;
    public double txsell;

    public Conversor() {
        this.txbuy = 0;
        this.txsell = 0;
    }

    public void defineBuyTax (double tax) {           
        txbuy = tax;
    }

    public void defineSellTax (double tax) {
        txsell = tax;
    }

    void printTaxes() {
        System.out.println("Buy tax: "+txbuy);
        System.out.println("Sell tax : "+txsell);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing in `defineBuyTax`:

- Create a comepletely new Conversor
- Set this new Conversor's txbuy to the given tax
- Return that new Conversor

So you're only working on a new Conversor that is then returned by the method. However, at your method call `cm.defineBuyTax(6.0)`, you actually don't use the returned Conversor (that would be `Conversor newConv = cm.defineBuyTax(6.0);`).

I suspect that you actually want to work on the existing Conversor instead of a new one, so rewrite your function like this:

```
public void defineBuyTax (double tax) {
    this.txbuy = tax;
}
```

or

```
public Conversor defineBuyTax (double tax) {
    this.txbuy = tax;
    return this;
}
```

if you want to have the return value. Same for `defineBuyTax`, of course. The `Test` class doesn't need to be changed and should work now.